# Как посчитать без счетчика?

Tags: java, fileupload, linked-list

Есть файл, содержимое которого строки, каждая строка – число.
Например : 4 4.5 21.543 1 124.12
Нужно реализовать на языке Java или Groovy загрузку содержимого файла в двунаправленную очередь и подсчет количества загруженных элементов, используя только доступные для неё операции и минимально необходимое количество вспомогательной памяти (переменных). В частности, запрещается использовать вторую очередь в качестве переменной, а также подсчитывать элементы при загрузке из файла в очередь.

Двунаправленная очередь – структура данных, для которой доступны операции:

- Добавить число в начало очереди;
- Добавить число в конец очереди;
- Изъять число из начала очереди;
- Изъять число из конца очереди;

В качестве операции сравнения элементов может использоваться только операция сравнения чисел. После расчета очередь должна остаться в первоначальном виде. Структура очереди должна быть реализована в общем виде, без ориентации на алгоритм (например, не допускается использование счетчика элементов в качестве члена класса двунаправленной очереди).

Comment: Ну раз нужно реализовать - реализуйте. Вопрос то в чем?

Comment: @Ramzes `не допускается использование счетчика элементов в качестве члена класса двунаправленной очереди` , перечитайте внимательно еще раз.

Answer (score 0):

Возможным решением может быть использование метода  `.size()`. Используйте его после заполнения очереди. Таким образом Вы минуете явного использования счётчика.